# Modify an arg right after input, argparser

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I have an `ArgumentParser` instance, like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('something')
parser.add_argument('--something', '-s', action='store', required=False, type=argparse.Filetype('r'),
                    help='something')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

I am passing a json filename as an input. This works flaweless, when json files are in the same directory as script itself, but I am trying to move json to another directory.

So file structure would change from this:

```
| my_script.py
| a.json
| b.json
```

to this:

```
| my_script.py
| some_dir
|    | a.json
|    | b.json
```

The script still works, only if I give `some_dir/a.json` as an argument. This is intended I know, but I am trying to implement a solution which would allow to give only json name as an argument, but still refer to file in new directory.

I tried to create custom action instead of `'store'` but failed horribly.I also tried to make some changes to `__call__` function of `argparse.FileType`, but that didn't work either.

**Is there any other method to modify an argument value on input?**

Comment: I don't think `argparse` library or it's functions are meant for your purpose

Comment: @bigbounty Care to elaborate? I have several json files and I want to use certain one based on initial argument, the only problem is that I am moving them to subdirectory. argparse is an ideal solution. Longer way around this would be not checking it with FileType right after input, but instead store the value as string, modify it and then check if file exists, but I am trying to avoid big changes in code.

Comment: Instead of using `FileType`, just accept a string, the filename.  Then you can use standard `os` functions to add the dir and open the file.  `FileType` is just a convenience `type`, useful when you want to simply open a file for script use, but there's little point to modifying or expanding it.

Comment: If you want to modify something in `argparse`, look at the code for `argparse.FileType`.  You could copy it, and add the `dir` change.  The file opening is done by the `type` function, not the `store` Action.

Comment: @hpaulj Yep that what i did after all, I just didn't want to alter existing code too much. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also tried some custom changes to `FileType` and it worked :)

```
import argparse
import os


class FooBar(argparse.FileType):
    def __call__(self, string):
        if string != "-":
            string = os.path.join("lalala", "tralala", string)
        return super().__call__(string)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser('something')
parser.add_argument('--something', '-s', action='store', required=False, type=FooBar('r'),
                    help='something')

args = parser.parse_args(["-s", "ahoj.txt"])
```

Output

```
usage: something [-h] [--something SOMETHING]
something: error: argument --something/-s: can't open 'lalala\tralala\ahoj.txt': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'lalala\\tralala\\ahoj.txt'
```

Comment: Exactly what i tried to accomplish, thanks. I did it the other way, with storing it as string, but i checked that solution and it worked, so I am marking it as correct answer